# How do I format am-pm-of-day to be "AM/PM" rather than "a.m./p.m."?

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

[`DateTimeFormatter`'s API reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) seems to miss details for formatting am-pm-of-day properly, I could always use `String.replace()` but I feel like it makes more sense to have an option change a.m. to AM and/or p.m. to PM using "aaa...". Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The format is based on the localisation, changing it may not make sense

Comment: @MadProgrammer Not quite sure what that means but in that case, [why is the example "PM"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)?

Comment: What I mean is - not every language/localisation uses `am` and `pm` (or variations of), so it might not make sense to try and change it, as it could have adverse effects when used in different localisations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Localized per CLDR

When formatting the textual representation of a date-time object, decisions about capitalization and abbreviation are matters left to the rules of localization. Those rules are defined as part of a [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html) object. In the latest versions of Java built on the codebase of the OpenJDK project, the `Locale` class gets its localization data from the [*Common Locale Data Repository (CLDR)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Locale_Data_Repository) maintained by the Unicode Consortium.

So no, there is no way to specify use of “AM” versus “a.m.” other than to specify one `Locale` object versus another.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ) ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ) ;
String outputCaFr = zdt.format( f.withLocale( Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) ) ;
String outputUkEn = zdt.format( f.withLocale( Locale.UK) ) ;
```

If you insist on a particular format, you’ll have to do the string manipulation yourself. But I suggest letting `Locale`, `DateTimeFormatter`, and the CLDR do their work of localizing rather than hard-coding trivial formatting tweaks.

Note that the CLDR, and therefore the `Locale` & `DateTimeFormatter` classes, support sub-cultures. Explore the CLDR’s definitions if the higher-level culture does not meet your expectations. One of the sub-cultures may hold the choice of localization rules you want.

Comment: Any reason why the example given is "PM" and not "p.m."?

Comment: @imashnake_ The JavaDoc uses an arbitrarily chosen example. Likely the example was whatever popped into the head of the technical writer that day. Different strokes for different folks. Some cultures use one format, others another. Neither is correct, neither is wrong.